# EF Core 5 - New Migrations Adding Alter ColumnStatements For Every Identity Column

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I recently updated from EF Core 3 to EF Core 5, since the update I was able to add 1 new migration without a problem.  Since then though every migration I add is adding Alter column statements for every identity column in the database.  These columns already existed as identity columns prior to the update to EF Core 5.

Attempting to run the migration results in an error:

> To change the IDENTITY property of a column, the column needs to be dropped and recreated.

There have been no changes to these columns since the previous migration and I do not know why EF Core is attempting to alter them.

Example alter column in the up method:

```
migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
    name: "UserID",
    table: "Users",
    type: "int",
    nullable: false,
    oldClrType: typeof(int),
    oldType: "int")
    .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1");
```

Comment: This sounds similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65319430/entity-framework-core-output-db-agnostic-with-version-5.  You may comment on the corresponding opened GitHub issue https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23714, or open new one there (probably with repro), because "by design" or not, if the behavior you are  describing (creating migration which fails when applying) is true, then it is unacceptable breaking change/bug.

Comment: Asked the same question and added a reproduction of the issue on github. 
https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/23755

Answer (score -1):

me too, got this problem too.

```
 migrationBuilder.AlterColumn<int>(
            name: "Id",
            table: "VerifyCodes",
            type: "int",
            nullable: false,
            oldClrType: typeof(int),
            oldType: "int")
            .Annotation("SqlServer:Identity", "1, 1");
```

Comment: Since this is not an attempt to provide assistance to the OP, it doesn't add value to them or anyone viewing this question.